# Expanding a variable containing an equals sign and curly braces

Tags: bash, variable

I'm writing a script that uses rsync and excludes files based on certain settings. I end up with an exclude flag that has a format of `--exclude={foo, bar, baz}`.

However, upon trying to expand it within the `rsync` command, I noticed the flag is escaped. From the bash debugger, I can see my command of `rsync $excludes` becomes `rsync '--exclude={foo,bar,baz}'`, rather than the expected `rsync --exclude={foo,bar,baz}`. Doing some testing, I found that any string containing `=`, `{`, or `}` will get wrapped in single quotes when expanded. Short of using eval on a constructed string, is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you really want it to expand to `--exclude={foo,bar,baz}` or are you trying to have brace expansion expand it to: `--exclude=foo --exclude=bar --exclude=baz`?

Comment: The former is the goal.

Comment: I also think that isn't the right syntax.  Should be `--exclude foo`.  I don't think rsync takes braces either though.

Comment: Using the equals sign is the correct syntax.

Comment: From the man page, `--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN`

Comment: So what are the braces for though?

Comment: I was using them for globbing, though I do suppose that means I was using brace expansion.

Comment: The single quotes are not part of the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion won't occur when quoted.  You should also store arguments in an array rather than a variable (when possible).

I think the following should work for you:

```
excludes=( $(--exclude={foo,bar,baz}) )
rsync "${excludes[@]}"
```

Comment: This does not work. This expands to `rsync '--exclude=foo' '--exclude=bar' '--exclude=baz'`

Comment: @ollien: That is what you need.  `--exclude={foo,bar,baz}` would be a syntax error to rsync

Comment: rsync does not recognize the flag when it is prepended by a single quote.

Comment: The single quote doesn't actually go to rsync,  it will be consumed by the shell

Comment: My mistake. I had messed up my globbing in my testing. Thank you!

Comment: You definitely do not need the `echo` in there.  `excl=( --exclude={a,b,c} )` works in `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

> From the bash debugger, ... any string containing =, {, or } will get wrapped in single quotes when expanded.

If you mean the `xtrace` output (`set -x`), it does indeed like to display arguments in single quotes when they contain special characters. The output is in a format that would be usable as input to the shell.

That doesn't mean the quotes are part of the string, though.

Compare:

```
$ echo abc def\ ghi
+ echo abc 'def ghi'
abc def ghi

$ echo abc \'def\ ghi\'
+ echo abc ''\''def ghi'\'''
abc 'def ghi'
```

Though as far as I can see, it doesn't bother to quote strings containing the equal sign.